# specs2 run a specific test

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm trying to run a specific test with `specs2` and I'm running into one minor issue there. This is the code I'm running:

```
import org.specs2._

class DemoSpec2 extends Specification {
  def is = s2"""

  This is a specification to check the 'Hello world' string

  The 'Hello world' string should
    contain 11 characters              ${Set11().e1}        ${tag("feature")}
    start with 'Hello'                 ${Set2().e2}         ${tag("abc")}

                                       """

  case class Set11(){ def e1 = 1 must_== 1 }
  case class Set2(){ def e2 = 1 must_== 1 }

}
```

The `${tag("feature")}` part makes an extra line in the output. So it looks like:

```
[info]   The 'Hello world' string should
[info]     + contain 11 characters
[info]         
[info]     + start with 'Hello'
```

I don't want the extra line. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, this is a reporting bug (fixed in the latest 2.2-SNAPSHOT). In the meantime things should be ok if you suppress spaces:

```
import org.specs2._

class DemoSpec2 extends Specification {
  def is = s2"""

  This is a specification to check the 'Hello world' string

  The 'Hello world' string should
    contain 11 characters              ${Set11().e1}${("feature")}
    start with 'Hello'                 ${Set2().e2}${tag("abc")}

                                   """
  case class Set11(){ def e1 = 1 must_== 1 }
  case class Set2(){ def e2 = 1 must_== 1 }
}
```